# IS there a way to add CommandFlags to a helper function?

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autocad-plugin

Currently trying to build a command which iterates through a BlockTable recursively, creating new drawings for each component BlockTableRecord. To do so, I need to lock each new document to properly edit it, which I'm trying to do via the Document.LockDocument() function. Since this command uses a recursive helper function, however, it throws a "DocumentLock is a type which is not valid in the given context" error which I believe is caused by the function lacking the "CommandFlags.Session" flag. Is there any way to attach this flag to a helper function? I've included my function's code below, thanks.

```
public List<string> BTRRecursor(BlockTableRecord bTR, string filepath)
        {
            Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
            Database db = doc.Database;
            Editor ed = doc.Editor;
            var filepaths = new List<string>();

            foreach (ObjectId internalObj in bTR)
            {
                Transaction trans = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();
                try
                {
                    BlockTableRecord internalBTR = trans.GetObject(internalObj, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTableRecord;
                    if (internalBTR.Name.Contains("_MR_"))
                    {
                        string strTemplatePath = "acad.dwt";
                        Document newDoc = Application.DocumentManager.Add(strTemplatePath);
                        using (DocumentLock lock = newDoc.LockDocument()) {
                            BlockTable nDBT = trans.GetObject(newDoc.Database.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTable;
                            nDBT.Add(internalBTR);
                            //toDWG 
                            //Create new file
                            //Open its BTR for write
                            //Set its BTR to internalBTR

                            filepaths.Append("DWG Filepath");
                        }
                    }

                    else if (internalBTR.Name.Contains("_NMR_"))
                    {
                        BTRRecursor(internalBTR, Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath + @"\" + internalBTR.Name).FullName);

                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    trans.Dispose();
                }
            }

            return filepaths;
        }
```

Comment: You do not need any recursion, the BlockTable of a Database contains all the BlockTableRecord of this Database and a BlockTableRecord cannot contain any other BlockTableRecord it only contains Entities. So, in your code, internalBTR will always be null.

Comment: Is there any way to access an enumeration of all nested blocks within a given block then? Thanks for the reply btw!

Answer (score 0):

I posted an example in response to your post in the [Autodesk forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/getting-and-exporting-all-nested-blocks-within-a-given-block/m-p/10391877#M69364). Here's another one in a more functional style.

```
    static IEnumerable<BlockTableRecord> GetNestedBlockTableRecords(BlockTableRecord source, Transaction tr)
    {
        foreach (var btr in source.Cast<ObjectId>()
            .Where(id => id.ObjectClass.DxfName == "INSERT")
            .Select(id => (BlockReference)tr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead))
            .Select(br => (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(br.BlockTableRecord, OpenMode.ForRead)))
        {
            yield return btr;
            foreach (var item in GetNestedBlockTableRecords(btr, tr))
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```